# AngularJS For Commercial site

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We are starting to develop our commercial site to replace the current one.

We are afraid from performance issues.

Our data is not very heavy at a single page, 150 Data binds at the most per page.

We will use AngularJS 1.2 to support IE8.

As at the internet, some of our users does not use fast computer (8% uses explorer 8).

Do you think we will suffer from performance issues at users that use Explorer 8 and have not-so-new computer more than a regular site (not using AngularJS)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should also check SEO with AngularJS. It might be a little bit problematic for the time being...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really dont think that using angularjs will have any adverse impact on the speed of site overall. infact if you keep an eye on certain basic performance issues of angular, you can gain a lot more by using angularjs. thing to keep eye on

1. ng-repeats : total time for rendering [link](http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/)
2. $watch count : [link](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef)
3. reduce no of filters on page
4. pagination

note : all above points are interlinked...

while choosing angular, its not only performance, but code maintainability, code reuse, tdd(less bugs) are the points to look at ...